# Помогите понять Random

Tags: java, случайные-числа

Вот строка.

```
int count = 0 + randomGlas.nextInt(100-0);
```

Только я её вообще не понимаю, а именно часть `0 + randomGlas.nextInt(100-0);` что за `0` к которому я прибавляю `randomGlas.nextInt` и что за `(100-0)`.

Как задавать нужный диапазон? Например нужно сгенерировать целое число в диапазоне от 1 до 6.

Answer (score 1):

Метод [`nextInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-) класса `Random` генерирует значения от 0 (включительно) до переданного ему числа (не включая его), т.е. в вашем случае от 0 до 99.

Если нужно получать значения не с нуля, а с какого-то другого числа, то нужно к полученному значению прибавлять нижнюю границу, а от максимального значения наоборот ее вычитать. Т.е. если нужно генерировать значения от a до b (опять же, включая a, но не включая b), то код будет такой:

```
 int count = a + randomGlas.nextInt(b - a);
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное